# Invalid default value - Django and python

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
   project_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   PROJECT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
      ('E-Commerce','E-Commerce'),
      ('Business','Business'),
   )

  APPLICATION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
      ('Android','Android'),
      ('iOS','iOS'),
      ('Windows','Windows'),
  )
 project_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PROJECT_TYPE_CHOICES, 
 default='E-Commerce')
 application_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, 
 choices=APPLICATION_TYPE_CHOICES, default='Windows')

 def __str__(self):
    return self.project_name
```

when I do makemigrations it's working fine. but while does migrate it shows below error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1067, "Invalid default value for 
'application
_type'")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `application_type` field only has a size of 3 characters, but your default (and other values) exceed that limit. Just extend it to 7 characters. Same goes for the `project_type` field. You will need to recreate the migration.

```
project_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PROJECT_TYPE_CHOICES, default='E-Commerce')
application_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=APPLICATION_TYPE_CHOICES, default='Windows')
```

Now that I look at it, I think you confused what `max_length` refers to. It's the size of the values in characters, not number of possible options.

Comment: I did as ur advice but it showing same error AGAIN!!!!                              
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
    choices=PROJECT_TYPE_CHOICES, default='E-Commerce')
    application_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
    choices=APPLICATION_TYPE_CHOICES, default='Windows')'

Comment: Did you delete and recreate the migration?

Comment: It is working after I delete and redo migrations! THANKS :)

Comment: Since everything worked, please accept the answer (click the checkmark to the left of the answer).